# How to customize ArcGIS Silverlight API 2.4 legend?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am using Esri's ArcGIS Silverlight API 2.4 and below is my legend.

My map has one feature layer and one dynamic service layer with nested layers like below

```
Feature Layer A
Group Layer
Group A
Layer A1
Layer A2
Layer A3
Group B
Group B1
Layer B1
Layer B2
Group B2
Layer B2
.....
```

'Feature Layer A' is the same as 'Layer A1' and I want to bring this 'Feature Layer A' to position of Layer A1. But this layer should be remain as feature layer only.

How can I do this? i.e feature layer inside the dynamic service layer group?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned because it has not attracted any activity, and its asker has not logged into this site, for 18 months.  Consequently, I am voting to close it.  It can always be re-opened in the future.